# CSS div tags that perfectly cover parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want 4 child divs to have a bottom border that completely covers the parent's bottom border. Reason being is the parent bottom border is the outline of the "not clicked" and the child div being the coloured bottom border of the "clicked" tab. How can I achieve this behavior?

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-slick-playground-d5f1c?file=/Navbar.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Tab from "./Tab";
import { StyledTabs, NavbarOutline } from "./StyledNavbar";

const Navbar = ({ value, children, tabFilter, contentFilter }) => {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(value[0].title);

  const onClickTabItem = tab => {
    setActiveTab(tab);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <NavbarOutline>
        <ol>
          {value.map(child => {
            const { title } = child;
            return (
              <Tab
                activeTab={activeTab}
                key={title}
                title={title}
                handleClick={onClickTabItem}
              />
            );
          })}
        </ol>
      </NavbarOutline>
      <div>
        {value.map(child => {
          if (child.title !== activeTab) return undefined;
          return <StyledTabs className="content">{child.title}</StyledTabs>;
        })}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export const NavbarOutline = styled.div`
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e3e3e3;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
  scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none; /* Safari and Chrome */
  }
`;

export const StyledTabs = styled.button.attrs(props => ({
  className: props.className
}))`
  &.not-active {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 16px 31px 16px 31px;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -18px;
  }
  &.active {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #2b8000;
    line-height: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 16px 31px 16px 31px;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #2b8000;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -18px;
  }
  &.content {
    list-style: none;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    float: left;
  }
`;
```

Comment: ol would need a reset on margin/padding , also it is supposed to have lis for children, nothing else. maybe turning that ol without  li into a nav would be a good idea. border can also be faked via box-shadow : https://codesandbox.io/s/navbar-component-xzw1v

Comment: @G-Cyrillus THANK YOU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to add `width: 25%;` to the `button`s and `padding-inline-start: 0` to the `ol`.

Agreed with G-Cyrillus that `ol` should be a `nav` element.

Comment: I love you. You don't know how long this took me to figure out

Comment: Chrome DevTools/Firefox Developer Tools are great tools, just right-click an element  and click "Inspect Element" and whenever you hover over an element in the Elements/Inspector pane, it highlights it and shows different colors for the element and any borders, margins, and padding. Chrome's "Computed" pane to the right of Elements and Firefox's "Layout" > "Box Model" pane under Inspector show numbers for each of these, so you'd have seen that the `ol` had padding. Also useful to change the CSS in the Styles/Rules pane and try things out without refreshing.